# Specs2 - "should not equal to" - how to check for non-equality?

Tags: scala, matcher, specs2

There are lot of [examples](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.8.9/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#equality) about how to check for equality in Specs2, but no examples on how to check for non-equality.

I tried (among other things) the following but it did not work :

```
"type safe get should work" in {
  Get("/SimpleLine") ~> getRoute[SimpleLine] ~> check {
    responseAs[String] shouldEqual "my name is SimpleLine"
    responseAs[String] shouldNot equal to "my name is SimpleLine2"
  }
}
```

how can I make this work ?

How can I check for non-equality in Specs2 ?

Google did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either one of the followings:

- `"a" should not equalTo "b"`
- `"a" shouldNotEqual "b"`
- `"a" should_!= "b"`
- `"a" must not equalTo "b"`
- `"a" mustNotEqual "b"`
- `"a" must_!= "b"`